# Representation of groups with generators and relations

Tags: group-theory, gap

Every finite small group in  GAP has an id. Now my question is:
Is there a way to find a presentation of a given SmallGroup(m,n)?

By presentation, I mean a set of generators and a set of relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following commands:

```
G:=SmallGroup(m,n);
H:=Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G));
RelatorsOfFpGroup(H);
```

Comment: Sometimes you can also use `SimplifiedFpGroup` to try to reduce the number of generators (see example [here](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups.html). `SmallGroup` returns a group in so called pc presentation, having a special set of generators - very efficient for calculations, but not necessarily of minimal possible order.